# How to call a Stored procedure form a user defined function In SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server

How to call a Stored procedure form a user defined function In SQL 2000

Comment: Should move this over to http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

officially you can't.

but you can try this trick:

```
-- add 'loopback' linkedserver 
if exists (select * from master..sysservers where srvname = 'loopback')
    exec sp_dropserver 'loopback'
go
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'loopback',
    @srvproduct = N'',
    @provider = N'SQLOLEDB', 
    @datasrc = @@servername
go

select * from openquery(loopback, 'exec yourSproc') 
go
```

Comment: That's about the sketchiest thing I've ever seen. I want to upvote you, not because I think that's a good idea, but because I respect your ingenuity...

Comment: upvote away :)
this method is actually used for things like that quite often and successfully.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31724&seqNum=2), one of the limitations is that you can't call an SP from a UDF.

One of the features of a UDF is that they're deterministic - calling them repeatedly with the same input values will result in the same output values (also assuming the underlying data isn't changing). If you call other objects from a UDF, SQL Server can't guarantee that this will remain true - that the UDF will remain deterministic. For example, if you call a SP from your UDF, even if the SP is currently deterministic (doesn't contain any non-deterministic functions, like GETDATE), there's no guarantee that won't change.

For an explanation of what it means to be (non-)deterministic, check out [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091(SQL.90).aspx)